# Invisible Notion table whose rows have page as parent

Tags: notion-api

The company I work for has been helping a Notion client to migrate to another knowledge base / wiki solution. Our ETL pipeline consistently failed for a single page, and it turns out that page has a child page, which in turn has an invisible table whose rows all have the root page as it's parent. This violated some contrains on the end format we were trying to convert it to, and so the transformation step failed.

Here's what these blocks look like in API 'language':

```
{
  "object": "block",
  "id": "<ROW_ID>",
  "parent": {
    "type": "page_id",
    "page_id": "<ROOT_PAGE_ID>",
  },
  ...
  "type": "table_row",
  "table_row": {
    "cells": [],
  }
}
```

It should be notes that these do not appear as children of the root page block or even the child page block, but rather as children of a table deeper in block tree.

Is this normal behaviour or a bug? Did I miss something in the API docs? THe [documentation](https://developers.notion.com/reference/block#table) doesn't say anything about such cases.